# [Vue warn]: Property or method "games" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I'm having problems whit vue.js.  I'm new to this and can't see what is wrong in the code.

My main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
import { rtdbPlugin } from 'vuefire';


Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(rtdbPlugin);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;


new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

My firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';

const app = firebase.initializeApp({ ... });

export const db = app.database();
export const gamesRef = db.ref('Games');
```

My App.vue component

```
<template>
    <b-container>
        <div class="page-header">
            <h2 class="text-center">Game Manager</h2>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <b-row>
            <b-col lg="4">
                <b-form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit()">
                    <b-form-group label="Titolo" label-for="titolo">
                        <b-form-input type="text" id="titolo" name="titolo" v-model="newGame.Titolo" v-on:change="onChange()"></b-form-input>
                    </b-form-group>
                    <b-form-group label="Software House" label-for="softwarehouse">
                        <b-form-input type="text" id="softwarehouse" name="softwarehouse" v-model="newGame.SoftwareHouse" v-on:change="onChange()"></b-form-input>
                    </b-form-group>
                    <b-form-group label="Tipo" label-for="tipo">
                        <b-form-select id="tipo" name="tipo" v-model="newGame.Tipo" :options="gameTypes"></b-form-select>
                    </b-form-group>
                    <b-form-group label="Piattaforma" label-for="piattaforma">
                        <b-form-select id="piattaforma" name="piattaforma" v-model="newGame.Piattaforma" :options="gamePlatforms"></b-form-select>
                    </b-form-group>

                    <b-btn type="submit" variant="primary" :disabled="submitDisabled">Aggiungi</b-btn>
                </b-form>
                <br/>
            </b-col>
            <b-col lg="8">
                <b-table :items="games" :fields="fields">
                    <template slot="Tipo" slot-scope="data">{{getGameType(data.item.Tipo)}}</template>
                    <template slot="Piattaforma" slot-scope="data">{{getPiattaforma(data.item.Piattaforma)}}</template>
                    <template slot=" " slot-scope="data">
                        <b-btn size="sm" variant="warning">X</b-btn>
                        <b-btn size="sm" variant="secondary">M</b-btn>
                    </template>
                </b-table>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</template>

<script>
    import { gamesRef } from './firebase';
    import { gameTypeEnum, piattaformaEnum } from './models/game';

    export default {
        firebase: {
            games: gamesRef
        },
        data() {
            return {
                gameTypes: gameTypeEnum.properties,
                gamePlatforms: piattaformaEnum.properties,
                fields: ['Titolo', 'SoftwareHouse', 'Tipo', 'Piattaforma', ' '],
                newGame: {
                    Titolo: '',
                    SoftwareHouse: '',
                    Tipo: gameTypeEnum.FPS,
                    Piattaforma: piattaformaEnum.PC
                },
                submitDisabled: true
            };
        },
        methods: {
            getPiattaforma(value) {
                return this.gamePlatforms[value].text;
            },
            getGameType(value) {
                return this.gameTypes[value].text;
            },
            onSubmit() {
                gamesRef.push(this.newGame);
                this.newGame.Titolo = '';
                this.newGame.SoftwareHouse = '';
                this.submitDisabled = true;
            },
            onChange() {
                this.submitDisabled = this.SoftwareHouse === '' || this.Titolo === '';
            },
            onDelete(game) {
                gamesRef.child(game['.key']).remove();
            }

        }
    };
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    .page-header{
        background-color: #226622;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .page-header h2{
        padding-top: 8px;
    }
</style>
```

The code is from a tutorial to learn Vue.js,  after compilation and launch is everithing Ok but no data is readed from the FireBase DB. Instead this error shows up in the console: 
[Vue warn]: Property or method "games" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

I have done some reaserch but find nothing to help me out with it.

Comment: Watch or read your tutorial carefuly again. Your mistake is easy to fix, you have just missed something :)

Comment: Well,  i have watched the tutorial 3 or 4 times the only things that i miss is the line
import './firebase.js' in the main.js file. 
After adding it the problem is not solved :( 
I think that somethong t do with the versions of Vue and VueFire,  taht i use, thay are newer than that in the tutorial it seems, but still haven't find nothing to help me :)

Comment: @AdamOrlov found what i've missed on the web,  but now there is another problem the buttons on the table template are not rendering :(

Comment: The slot name you are trying to use is probably wrong `slot=" "`. I don't think that Bootstrap-Vue would make a `slot` named `" "` "empty string" ;-) Check in the docs for the right name.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that your template refers to a variable, `games`, that isn't defined. If you look at your code, you can see you tell firebase to use `gamesRef` to refer to the games data. I believe if you just change your template to use `gamesRef` instead of `games`, you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved,  i was missing a initialization in the data() properties :) 
It was only matter to add games: [], in the return of data().

Thanks all for help :)